# How to disable Gxt ListView selection

Tags: gwt, gxt

Using ListView component of GXT-2.2.3 and tried different options to disable the selection. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would think `ListView.setEnabled(false);` should do the job for you.

If this doesn't work, you could add a listener for the `Select` event, and set the `ListView`'s selection to null, though this won't **disable** selection, but rather undo it.

Comment: Listening for the `Select` event will let you undo it, but even better would be to listen for `BeforeSelect`, and invoke cancel to prevent the selection from occurring at all. Both of these events can be listened for on the `ListViewSelectionModel` instance attached to the `ListView`.